# How do I use this JQuery code to validate a password?

Tags: jquery, passwords

I found [this password validation code,](https://www.okpay.com/en/account/signup.html) and am trying to figure out what the first few lines mean.  Namely:

- Is ".opts" a variable or part of Javascript?
- How do I "hook up" this code to a given HTML password/textbox

code

```
$.fn.passwordStrength = function (options) {

    return this.each(function () {
// BEGIN - Don't understand
        var that = this; that.opts = {};
        that.opts = $.extend({}, $.fn.passwordStrength.defaults, options);
        that.div = $(that.opts.targetDiv);
        that.defaultClass = that.div.attr('class');
        that.percents = (that.opts.classes.length) ? 100 / that.opts.classes.length : 100;
// END - Don't understand

        this.div.append("<div class='pswstr smsgns passive'></div>");
        this.div.append("<div class='pswstr lgsgns passive'></div>");
        this.div.append("<div class='pswstr numb passive'></div>");
        this.div.append("<div class='pswstr char passive'></div>");
        this.div.append("<div class='pswstr symb passive'></div>");


        var specialsymbolPassed = false;
        var smallsymbolPassed = false;
        var largesymbolPassed = false;
        var lengthPassed = false;

        var numberRegex = new RegExp("([0-9]+)");
        var smallsymbolRegex = new RegExp("([a-z]+)");
        var largesymbolRegex = new RegExp("([A-Z]+)");
        var specialsymbolRegex = new RegExp("([^A-Za-z0-9]+)");

        v = $(this).keyup(function () {
            if (typeof el == "undefined")
            { this.el = $(this); }

            var dv = $(that.opts.targetDiv);

            if (smallsymbolRegex.test(this.value)) { toogleDv($(dv).find("div.smsgns"), true); smallsymbolPassed = true; }
            else { toogleDv($(dv).find("div.smsgns"), false); smallsymbolPassed = false ; }

            if (largesymbolRegex.test(this.value)) { toogleDv($(dv).find("div.lgsgns"), true); largesymbolPassed = true; }
            else { toogleDv($(dv).find("div.lgsgns"), false); largesymbolPassed = false; }

            if (this.value.length >= 8) { toogleDv($(dv).find("div.symb"), true); lengthPassed = true; }
            else { toogleDv($(dv).find("div.symb"), false); lengthPassed = false; }

            if (specialsymbolRegex.test(this.value) || numberRegex.test(this.value)) {
                specialSymbPassed = true;
                toogleDv($(dv).find("div.char"), true);
                toogleDv($(dv).find("div.numb"), true);
                }
            else {
                toogleDv($(dv).find("div.char"), false);
                toogleDv($(dv).find("div.numb"), false); 
                specialSymbPassed = false; 
             }

//            if (numberRegex.test(this.value)) { toogleDv($(dv).find("div.numb"), true); numberPassed = true; }
//            else { toogleDv($(dv).find("div.numb"), false); numberPassed = false; }


            if (smallsymbolPassed && largesymbolPassed && lengthPassed && specialSymbPassed) {
                $(dv).parent().addClass("pass");
                $(dv).addClass("pass");
            }
            else {
                $(dv).parent().removeClass("pass");
                $(dv).removeClass("pass");
            }

            //            var s = getPasswordStrength2(this.value);
            //            var p = this.percents;
            //            var t = Math.floor(s / p);
            //            if (t > 10) { t = 10; }
            //            //if (s >= 110)
            //            //t = this.opts.classes.length - 1;
            //            this.div.removeAttr('class').addClass(this.defaultClass);
            //            if (s > 0) { this.div.addClass(this.opts.classes[t - 1]); }
        })
    });

    function toogleDv($dv, Enable) {
        if (Enable) { $dv.removeClass("passive").addClass("active"); } else { $dv.removeClass("active").addClass("passive"); }
    }

    function getPasswordStrength2(H) {
        var numberRegex = new RegExp("([0-9]+)");
        var smallsymbolRegex = new RegExp("([a-z]+)");
        var largesymbolRegex = new RegExp("([A-Z]+)");
        var specialsymbolRegex = new RegExp("([^A-Za-z0-9]+)");
        var power = 0;
        if (numberRegex.test(H)) { power += 20; }
        if (smallsymbolRegex.test(H)) { power += 20; }
        if (largesymbolRegex.test(H)) { power += 20; }
        if (specialsymbolRegex.test(H)) { power += 20; }
        var l = Math.floor(H.length / 2);
        if (l > 6) { l = 6; }
        power += l * 5;
        if (H.length < 8) { if (power > 85) { power = 85; } }
        return power;
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

1. `that.opts` is a variable. It's where the passwordStrength plugin saves the options that you specified when invoking it. `$.extend()` is used to merge the options supplied as a parameter with the defaults.
2. You use it similarly to other jQuery plugins:

`$(selector).passwordStrength({ options });`

See how it's used at the beginning of [signup.js](https://www.okpay.com/js/signup.js) at the site you linked to.

If you Google "jquery password strength plugin" you'll find some other similar plugins, and they may actually have documentation.